# C server not receiving java/android client message

Tags: java, android, c, sockets

I am still new with sockets, and am having a little problem with creating an android client a c server.

The c server is runs well, and android client connects also well to the c server.
But the problem comes when communicating with the server. When I try to send a simple message, the server doesn't seem to receive it at all.

So here is the code of the server waiting for the message :

```
void readMsg(int client){
    char buffer[1024];
    int n = 0;

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    printf("waiting for message..\n");
    while(( n=recv(client, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1, 0)) > 0){
        printf("recv=%s\n", buffer);
    }

    printf("n=%d\n", n);
}
```

And nothing at all is displayed. It's blocked on `waiting for message..` .

And concerning the java code to send the message, here it is :

```
OutputStreamWriter osw;
PrintWriter pw;
try {
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
    pw = new PrintWriter(osw, true);
    pw.print(msg);
    pw.flush();

}catch(IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

[EDIT]

Just to provide more information, the function `readMsg()` is called just after starting the server and once the client is connected.

For more information, here is the way I connect to the server :

```
try{
   //I am sure that the host and port are correct
   Socket server = new Socket(host, port);

}catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Okay, so I found out what went wrong, I was in fact connecting twice to the server.
As a result it couldn't send the message through the right socket.

Sorry for everything and thank you for all your help

[/EDIT]

I've already tried several solutions by looking at several other posts on this site.

Thank you in advance for all help

Comment: is the message sent from client? how do you call readMsg() function on server?

Comment: Yes the message is sent from the client, android application.

Comment: Can you 'telnet' to the C server and get it to print what you type at the telnet prompt? `telnet servername 1234` where servername and 1234 are the host and prorts you run the C server on...

Comment: When using telnet it works, the message is received

Comment: @ScriptorTux verify that client sent message

Comment: Does the C program continue/print the message if you do: `server.getOutputStream().close()` at the end?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: The only thing that makes sense, given these answers, is that your Java process is not connecting to your C server with the socket you call 'server'. Your issue is not related to the code you have shown here.

Comment: Make sure the java client is sending 1024 bytes. The recv() will block until that many bytes are ready (assuming it's a tcp socket)

Answer (score 0):

use a `println` instead of `print`, also wrap the `OutputStreamWriter` inside a `BufferedWriter`

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(osw), true);
pw.println(msg);
```

Comment: The recv should complete when the socket is closed, though... oh, crap, I asked to close the output stream, not the whole socket.

Comment: @ashoke Sorry, but it didn't change anything

Comment: are you creating the `server` socket inside `onCreate` ?, if so consider doing it in a seperate thread.

Comment: No, the class controling the client extends `AsyncTask` and overrides the function `doInBackground()`

Comment: where are you testing this, emulator->localhost ?, you mentioned `socket` connects ok, can you add `Log.e("socktest",str)` calls, and share the log